# Body from Func<T>

Tags: c#, expression-trees, func

how can I get a body from function

```cs
Func<bool> methodCall = () => output.SendToFile(); 

if (methodCall())
    Console.WriteLine("Success!");
```

I need to get this `output.SendToFile()` as a string

Another example:

```cs
string log = "";

public void Foo<T>(Func<T> func)
{
    try
    {
        var t = func();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        //here I need to add the body of the lambda
        // log += func.body;
    }
}

public void Test()
{
    var a = 5;
    var b = 6;
    Foo(() => a > b);
}
```

Edit:
For more information on this topic see: [Expression Trees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx)

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are asking. Do you want a method you can pass "methodCall" into and have it return "output.SendToFile()"? What should it return for other methods, like `Console.WriteLine`?

Comment: I just need to get this info from lambda "output.SendToFile()" this data I can add to the log, if I'll get an exception

Comment: Could you do exception handling and logging inside SendToFile? The method should also be at the top of the exception stack trace (which you should maybe log anyway).

Comment: Please, confirm that Daniel answered your question or clarify what you need. Do you mean that you want the WriteLine to be within the body of the lambda expression? That's how I understood it first.

Comment: Do you mean that you want the WriteLine to be within the body of the lambda expression? That's how I understood it first.

Comment: Sorry if mislead, in second example I need to have "a >b" as a string

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't. A `Func<T>` is nothing you can easily analyze. If you want to analyze a lambda, you need to create a `Expression<Func<bool>>` and analyze it.

Getting the body of an expression is simple:

```
Expression<Func<bool>> methodCall = () => output.SendToFile(); 
var body = methodCall.Body;
```

`body` would be a `MethodCallExpression` you could further analyze or just output via `ToString`. Using `ToString` won't result exactly in what you would like to have, but it contains that information, too.

For example, executing `ToString()` on `body` in LINQPad results in something like this:

```
value(UserQuery+<>c__DisplayClass0).output.SendToFile()
```

As you can see, `"output.SendToFile()"` is there.

To actually execute the code defined by an expression, you first need to compile it:

```
var func = methodCall.Compile();
func();
```

Which can be shortened to this:

```
methodCall.Compile()(); // looks strange but is valid.
```

Comment: But note that expressions cannot contain statements.

Comment: thanks a lot, I think it will be enough for the log information