# Stubbing function expression of repository object using Rhino Mocks

Tags: c#, mocking, rhino-mocks

I'm using Rhino Mocks to unit test a service method that makes the following call:

```
var form = Repo.GetOne<Form>(f => f.Id == formId, "FormTemplate, Event");
```

The Repo.GetOne method signature is:

```
TEntity GetOne<TEntity>(
            Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
            string includeProperties = null)
            where TEntity : class, IEntity;
```

So far I have only managed to do this by ignoring the Function Expression argument:

```
_mockRepo.Stub(
    r => 
    r.GetOne<Form>(                    
      Arg<Expression<Func<Form, bool>>>.Is.Anything,
      Arg<string>.Is.Equal("FormTemplate, Event")))
    .Return(form);
```

How do I stub the Repo.GetOne method in order to set the return value when the method is called with arguments `f => f.Id == formId, "FormTemplate, Event"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you setup Stub/Mocks, the value used for the arguments must return true when you call `mockArg.Equals(runtimeArg)`.  Your `Func<>` isn't going to do that, so you're best bet is to use the `Arg<T>.Matches()` constraint, which takes a function that, given the stub inputs, returns true if the runtime input are a match.

Unfortunately, looking at the contents of the `Func<T>` delegate is not straightforward.  (Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/17673890/682840)

```
  var myArgChecker = new Function<Expression<Func<Form, bool>>, bool>(input =>
        {
            //inspect input to determine if it's a match
            return true; //or false if you don't want to apply this stub                    
        });


_mockRepo.Stub(
    r => 
    r.GetOne<Form>(                    
      Arg<Expression<Func<Form, bool>>>.Matches(input => myArgChecker(input)),
      Arg<string>.Is.Equal("FormTemplate, Event")))
    .Return(form);
```

Comment: Thanks, this really helped. I ended up with a solution by combining this approach with the expression equality checker in this SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24528357/95423